# What is in the 4-pin DC cable?

Tags: electrical, power-backup, adapter

I received a used DVR, which expects a power supply [like this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/4-Pin-AC-Adapter-For-LOREX-L23WD-L23WD800-Integrated-8CH-LCD-DVR-DC-Power-Supply/351773458859) -- note the 4-pin connector. I want to feed the DVR and the cameras from a battery-backed system like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P1JOX7G) so that the whole setup survives a power outage for at least a few minutes.

The cameras are easy -- they want only the `+` and the `-` of the DC. But what's in the *four* contacts of the DVR? I can guess, the third one is ground -- what of the fourth? Does the connector have a name I can put into Google?

Comment: Start by looking on the chassis of the machine for what voltage it wants. Supplying the wrong DC voltage will have "mixed results at best" lol.  Supplying reverse polarity DC will end in disaster.

Comment: Actually, the DVR seems to function just fine with 14V supplied by a power adapter from an old (late 90ies) Samsung LCD television set -- with the same "DIN" connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images in the eBay post show a 12v 7a power supply with a pinout on the power brick. The pinout shows only a 12v positive (pin) and ground (barrel).

The connector is called a 4P Power Snap and Lock, but you may also find it loosely described as a 4 pin DIN connector. The latter description is slightly inaccurate.

If you have a volt meter, you can confirm that the inside four pins are all 12v. It's not out of the question that all four pins are hot in order to handle the relatively high current capacity of the 7 amp power supply or 7 amp power requirements of the DVR.

Comment: Thanks! I do not have the power supply pictured -- I want to use a battery-backed alternative -- so I can't measure it. I'll look up the names you listed, thanks again.